# How to change language of class library in VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I've made vb console application project in vs 2010 and added one class with simple code.

Then I replace this code with c# code, and "i've changed extension from .vb to .cs .

But I can't run this application because I have got error:

'Sub Main' was not found in 'Test_VB_ClassLibrary'

Hwo can I convert my project to be c#?

Comment: c# uses public static Main  instead of sub Main you will need to change that first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You will be better off re-creating your project**, that said if you really want to do this then open up the `vbproj` file in notepad / a text editor and find the following line:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.VisualBasic.targets" />
```

Change it to the following:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

You also need to rename the file to have a `.csproj` extension so that Visual Studio displays the project correctly.

Your current build problem is caused because the name of the startup object has also changed - to fix this go to the "Application" tab under the project properties and make sure that the startup object property is set correctly.

At this point your project is now a C# project file - any .vb files present in the project (including designer generated files) won't build correctly and you will need to remove them or convert them to C#.

This *works* (I have tried it), however there is a good chance that you have other problems with incorrect MSBuild properties being set, for example after performing the above steps:

- The project didn't have the "Define DEBUG constant" checkbox ticked for the debug configuration
- It also had a load of entries in the "Suppress warnings" property that aren't normally there for a C# project

**Once again my advice is just to re-create your project from scratch instead.**

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that you *can* change the language of a project - it would change file extension and everything. It's probably simpler to just create a new project... if you want it to be in the same place, just rename and move the old one first.

EDIT: As noted in comments, you *can* change the language. But please, just make the right decision upfront or take the hit of creating a new project.

Comment: you can change the languge it is just incredibly annoying to do it and usually easier to create a new project and bring your code over unless it is a large project

Answer (score 2):

You can't just change a file extension and expect this to work. There are MANY other files and settings involved. Your error is because "Sub Main" doesn't exist in C# and your project settings under VB are saying that Sub Main is the startup location of your app.

You have to create a new project and re-write your code.